# Multiple Machine from same Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant

I developed a product with master slave architecture.
So, I should configure multiple machine for slave in vagrant. But actually this machines is not different from others. All slaves will be same configured machines but separated machines.

So, I think I should write one Vagrantfile and build ten times or what I want to.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks and best regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrantfile is a ruby script so you can run a loop to create as many slaves as you need.

Follow the tips from [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/tips.html)

```
(1..3).each do |i|
  config.vm.define "slave-#{i}" do |slave|
    slave.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.25.#{i}", auto_config: false
    slave.vm.provision "shell",
      inline: "echo hello from slave #{i}"
  end
end
```

This will creates 3 identical slaves with each a different IPs - you can add your specific configuration that will apply identically to all 3 machines.